# Multiple forms on a page

Tags: vue.js

I have been researching for hours now and I admit defeat. I have a page which lists a bunch of users and allows you to reset a users password. You click the reset button by the user and it brings up a modal box with the password reset form in.

I use Vue.js to validate the form and submit it, all using ajax (vue-resource). The list of users and unique modals is generated by Laravel in a blade view.

My question is, how do I have a unique Vue instance (or whatever I should do) for each form on the page?

My investigation suggests using components however I cannot seem to get this to work so not sure it is the right thing to do, as I would still have the same component multiple times on the page? (and each form has unique data (the user id)).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple component instances are in fact the way to go. If you a generating users inside a for loop, pass the user id as a property of the component.

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
    <form-component id="{{ $user->id }}"</form-component>
@endforeach

var FormComponent = Vue.extend({
        template: '<form> \
        <input name="user-{{id}}"></input>\
        <button>Submit</button> \
        </form>',
    props: ['id'],
});
```

[Passing Data with Props](http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Passing_Data_with_Props)

Comment: Thanks! Nice to know I'm looking in the right direction. I have a few things in the form and so would prefer to write out the form within the page instead of in the template property. I assume this is ok as long as its inside the component tag? As currently it keeps complaining about it being a fragment instance and the values aren't displaying per component.